# Connecting WordPress settings to domain

Tags: wp-config

I have having trouble getting my site http://www.triadmathtutor.com online with wordpress. On my home connection I can connect to the site correctly with these wp_config settings:

`// define('WP_SITEURL', 'www.triadmathtutor.com');`

`// define('WP_HOME', 'www.triadmathtutor.com;`

`define( 'DB_HOST', 'www.triadmathtutor.com’ );`

That is, `WP_SITE_URL` and `WP_HOME` are commented out. However, my website is not online. If I then uncomment `WP_SITE_URL` and `WP_HOME` I can’t connect to my site at all via `www.triadmathtutor.com`. If I got to the wordpress settings on `wp-admin` (with the config file settings mentioned above still commented out) , I see that:

WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are both set to:

`https://www.triadmathtutor.com`

I also believe that I noticed from before that whenever I had the values above uncommented I was getting strange things like a redirect to `http://www.triadmathtutor.com/www.triadmathtutor.com/` which looked wonky and obviously didn’t go to the website.

Other things I have tried:
With the above mentioned commented out on the local machine, I can ping `http://www.triadmathtutor.com` correctly, but it’s connecting to the local host ip address only.

Help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The blog I need help with is: `www.triadmathtutor.com`

Comment: those look like smart apostrophes.  try replacing `‘` with `'`

Comment: also are you trying to host this from your home computer? Visiting that site indicates it has an invalid SSL/TLS certificate, and that it's being served by Lando, a local dev environment designed for developers to build sites without having to connect to a remote server, akabuilding a site on your own computer, it's not intended for hosting the actual site. I've removed the wordpress.org tag as this isn't a question about wordpress.org, and the wordpress.com hosting tag as you aren't asking about a wp.com hosted site

Comment: Also, try to add https:// in front of the url.  `define(‘WP_SITEURL’, 'https://www.triadmathtutor.com');`

Comment: I literally cannot even submit a comment, so I have to provide my response in an answer: @rudtek - Thanks for the apostrophes thing, that is correct that it was the incorrect apostrophe. However, I checked, and I am indeed using the apostrophe you had mentioned to replace with. I did try your suggestion with https:// but it still is doing the same thing. Tom J Nowell - I am not using Lando. I am using wordpress that is connected via an nginx server. This is home web development so I am not even using any CMS other than wordpress that I downloaded. Please don't remove tags from my post untill y

Comment: Regardless of where the site is being hosted @Tomjnowell is right:  the domain isn't live.  You'll need to figure out if it IS being hosted and where.  The domain you provided has no DNS entries or Nameservers attached so no matter what you put to that domain it won't show.

Comment: Right. I'm wondering If Tom has a point, though. I never setup a wordpress server, but maybe a wordpress server is being set in the background. That's the only reason I can think of why my website returns the localhost when I ping of, but my nginx server points to it. If I stop my nginx server the website goes down, so there is still some connection there. 

Is there an auto-wordpress server setup when you install wordpress? I am 100% sure the domain hosting is google domains, as I have the domain there, but the dns server is not connecting yet. I know the dns is setup correctly there.

Comment: Wordpress won't set a server up. It needs to be set up for wordpress to work. Likely the reason it works on local is you have a redirect setup in your localhosts file.  You need to login to the domain registrar and setup the DNS to your hosting server (hopefully not your local computer).

Comment: I found a problem with my dns in that I was using capital letters and it seems like that doesn't work. Now my dns is setup correctly, just don't see the website. It is pinging to the right address, but nothing is returned.

Comment: I converted your answer to a comment, you need to be logged in with the same user that created the question to comment back. I mention Lando because visiting your site gives a certificate error as it's using certificates created by Lando. It's also very unusual to see full domain names listed like that for the DB host. Remember, WordPress is just a PHP application, there's no long running task that listens for requests in a PHP app, that's the job of Nginx/Apache and stuff lower down the stack. Your server should be able to handle serving CSS/JS/plain HTML files fine before touching WP

Comment: I've identified the problem, and rewritten my answer, with evidence to back it up

Answer (score 0):

Your site is not running on a web server, it's running on your local computer. Your DNS has been setup to point to `0.0.0.0` which is not a web server but a broadcast IP that always points to yourself:

[image]

[image]

This is why I thought you were running Lando, because I have a copy of Lando running on my machine.

It's also why your site doesn't work on other peoples computers, because they don't have your site running on their machine. In fact if they had a local dev environment they would see that instead.

To fix this, you need to remove the A record for 0.0.0.0 and replace it with an actual IP address that exists on the open web.

For example here is my website, and you can see in its DNS record is an IP for a machine at a popular cloud host:

[image]

If you wanted to host it on your own hardware at home, you'd need to find out your IP address and put that in your DNS records, making sure your home network knows to route the request to the correct machine.

Note though that:

- this violates the terms and services of most ISPs
- most ISPs rotate IP addresses every 24 hours, you'll need to request a fixed IP if your ISP offers that service
- this all counts towards your home bandwidth allocation. If your ISP gives you a 50gb allowance and I download a 10gb file from your server 5 times your site and internet will go down.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the actual production database values for `siteurl` and `home`.  Depending on your host and url rewrite rules and installation you probably need to make sure the values start with the protocol, http:// or https://.